# Handling the not authorized using custom attributes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, attributes, custom-attributes

I have this custom authorization class to check if a user is an admin:

```
public class IsAdminAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        private datacontext() db = new datacontext();
        protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
        {
            var isAuthorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
            if (isAuthorized)
            {
                var currentUser = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
                return db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == currentUser).Where(ut => ut.UserTypeID == 2).Count() == 1 ? true : false;
            }
            return isAuthorized;
        }

    }
```

and is used here:

```
[IsAdmin]
public ActionResult CreateUser()
{
    ViewBag.UserTypeID = new SelectList(db.UserTypes, "UserTypeId", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

and works ok but takes me back to my log in page when the user is not authorized. What I want to happen is for the user to be redirected somewhere with an error message popping up. How do I handle the denied access event?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How do I handle the denied access event?

Simply override the [`HandleUnauthorizedRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.handleunauthorizedrequest.aspx) method and return directly the view you like:

```
protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
    {
        ViewName = "Unauthorized"
    };
}
```

This will render `~/Views/Shared/Unauthorized.cshtml`. You could also pass view models, master pages, etc... to this `ViewResult`.